# does google org chart visualization api support mutliple managers (coheads)

Tags: google-visualization, orgchart

is there a way to support the use case where there are a bunch of people that report to two co heads of a group.  it doesn't look like it from my initial testing but wanted to verify to be sure.  i have a use case where some people report to Joe and some people report to Tom but some people report both to Joe and Tom as they are co heads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't. When you add the second relationship, it replaces the first (i.e. if you have "Mike reports to Tom" and then add "Mike reports to Joe" the chart will show "Mike reports to Joe").

From the [API documentation page](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Data_Format):

> Each node can have zero or one parent
>   node, and zero or more child nodes.

Comment: thanks . . thats unfortunate . . do you know how active anyone on google works on the org chart as i posted on the issues site but there seems to be some pretty old issues that haven't been addressed

Comment: I know Google guys keep adding to the visualization API constantly. Not sure about the org chart part.